# How to investigate the convegence of this sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

How to investigate the convegence of the following sequence using Cauchy's convergence test?

$$x_{n} = \frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[1]{2}+\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{3}+\sqrt{2}}+ ... +\frac{1}{\sqrt[n-1]{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}$$

Comment: Of course the sum does _not_ converge.

Comment: $$x_n > \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \frac{n}{2} \frac{1}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{2n}}} > \frac{n}{2} \frac{\sqrt{e}}{(en)^{1/(2n)}\sqrt{n}} > \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2(en)^{1/(2n)}}$$

Here we used the arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality and Stirling's inequality for factorials.

This result obviously means that the sequence diverges.

(Just as an alternative to Cauchy test, or comparison with harmonic series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x_n)$ does not converge. To see this, notice that
$$ \begin{split}
x_n &> \frac11+\frac1{\sqrt2+1}+\frac1{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}+\cdots\\
&>\frac12+\frac1{2\sqrt2}+\frac1{2\sqrt3}\\
&=\frac12\sum_1^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}.
\end{split}$$
For any positive integer $n\geq\sqrt n$, so $\frac1n\leq\frac1{\sqrt n}$. Thus
$$ x_n>\frac12\sum_1^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}>\frac12\sum_1^\infty\frac1n. $$
The rightmost sum is (half of) the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), which is well known not to converge. Since $x_n$ is always larger than it, then surely it does not converge as well.

Comment: The OP needs to use Cauchy's convergence test